# Spyder python version vs. currently active Anaconda version

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I created an Anaconda environment with Python 2.7, but when I start spyder from within that environment, it starts with Python 3.6 (the default for my Anaconda install). I have confirmed that just running `python` at the command line uses the expected version (2.7 when the environment is activated, 3.6 otherwise).

Shouldn't Spyder use the python of the currently active anaconda environment?

Or... how can I set enable this behavior?

Comment: Well, installing a separate version of spyder for the 2.7 environment, with the command `conda create -n <new environment name> python=2.7 spyder` seems to have done the trick. But is that really the intended way?

Comment: Yes, you need to install Spyder in your Python 2.7 environment for Spyder to work with that Python  version.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above:

Install a separate version of spyder for the 2.7 environment, with the command `conda create -n <new environment name> python=2.7 spyder`